# Is it possible to convert SVG files to OTF/TTF?

Tags: svg, font-face, cjk, truetype

I'm thinking about using DejaVu font to create a Ruby-like font for CJK scripts.
However I'm not sure about:

1. does DejaVu support CJK glyphs?
2. can I use a script to generate new glyphs in SVG then convert/package them in a font file?

By creating new glyphs I mean to append prononciation to non-alphabetical glyphs (e.g.  中+zhōng + 國 guó) already existing. So reuse as much as possible what is already here.

**Given data such** :

```
{ '中': 'zhōng', '國': 'guó' }
```

get final **OTF/TTF font result such:**

[image: End result]

Comment: This question may gain to be splited into 2 questions.

Answer (score 2):

http://icomoon.io/#docs/importing seems* allows to **"Import Icons"** (aka upload your SVGs), IconMoon then generate a font with these shapes.

*: I never tried myself. May be more troublesome than it seems.

Answer from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18479034/